# Maximizing space in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I want to see if there is a possible way for me to maximize space in a list. For example:

```
lists = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

Maximum Value = 4 #from user input

Output = [3, 0, 4, 4, 4]
```

Process in each step:

```
Start: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3] #start
       [3, 3, 3, 2, 4] #takes 1 number from lists[3] and puts it in lists[4] so that that is equal to 4
       [3, 3, 1, 4, 4] #takes 2 numbers from(since 4 - lists[3] = 2 lists[2] and puts it in lists[3]
Finish:[3, 0, 1, 4, 4] #puts 3 numbers from lists[1] and puts them in lists[2](4 - lists[2] = 3) and now that there is a zero it should stop the program
```

Basically, the code should start at the back and fill in space in each value going down the list until one of the values is equal to 4 or 0 or until it reaches the start of the list.

1 last thing:
This should work with any list length and even if there are 0's after the last number. For example:

```
list = [3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
MaximumValue = 4
 Step 1: [3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
         [3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
         [3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
         [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
         [3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
 Finish: [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4] #reached lists[0] so stop program
```

Comment: have you written any code?

Comment: No, i'm new to python so i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your example for "even if there are 0's after the last number" doesn't have 0's after the last number. And your "Process in each step" ends up with a different final answer than the desired output from the top. And, most importantly, what does "maximize space in a list" even mean? You're clearly trying to do _something_ here. At first It thought it required keeping the sum unchanged, but going from `[3, 3, 1, 4, 4]` to `[3, 0, 1, 4, 4]` clearly means that wild guess was wrong, so I'm completely at a loss as to what you want.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework assignment or similar? If so, if _you_ can't explain it, hopefully the _assignment_ explains it, so you can use that to help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all those intermediate steps. You can produce the list directly with easy division and remainder calculations.

```
>>> l = [3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
>>> m = 4
>>> [m] * (sum(l) / m) + [sum(l) % m] + [0] * (len(l) - sum(l) / m - 1)
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Comment: The new list should be [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4] and the 4 at lists[11] should still be there. Also the 1 should be at the start of the list not the near end.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code, maybe has better way.

```
lis = [3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]

MaximumValue = 4
start_index = 0
for i,v in enumerate(lis):
  start_index = i
  if v == 0:
    start_index = i - 1
    break

for i in range(start_index, 0, -1):
  diff = MaximumValue - lis[i]
  if diff >= 0:
    lis[i] += diff
    lis[i-1] -= diff
  if lis[i-1] == 0:
    break

print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
```